# Are there critical hit attacks?

Tags: pokemon-go

Yesterday i was training in a gym. my pokemon easily won the 3 first pokemon and fainted in the forth one, 3 times in a row. always my pokemon had different HP but slightly similar. but one time  my pokemon fainted fighting the 2nd pokemon ... so i was wondering if are there Critical Hit attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are critical hits.

The critical strike rate depends on the attack itself.

See here:

```
    Items {
      TemplateId: "V0022_MOVE_MEGAHORN"
      Move {
        UniqueId: V0022_MOVE_MEGAHORN
        AnimationId: 5
        Type: POKEMON_TYPE_BUG
        Power: 55
        AccuracyChance: 1
   >    CriticalChance: 0.05
        StaminaLossScalar: 0.12
        TrainerLevelMin: 1
        TrainerLevelMax: 100
        VfxName: "megahorn"
        DurationMs: 3200
        DamageWindowStartMs: 2400
        DamageWindowEndMs: 2700
        EnergyDelta: -100
      }
    }
```

Or here:

```
    Items {
      TemplateId: "V0032_MOVE_STONE_EDGE"
      Move {
        UniqueId: V0032_MOVE_STONE_EDGE
        AnimationId: 5
        Type: POKEMON_TYPE_ROCK
        Power: 55
        AccuracyChance: 1
   >    CriticalChance: 0.5
        StaminaLossScalar: 0.1
        TrainerLevelMin: 1
        TrainerLevelMax: 100
        VfxName: "stone_edge"
        DurationMs: 3100
        DamageWindowStartMs: 1400
        DamageWindowEndMs: 1800
        EnergyDelta: -100
      }
    }
```

Comment: nice! and what about the percentage of added damage?

Comment: It may be 150% of the base damage

Comment: @phoke, any solid source?

Comment: Haven't found evidence, but 50% extra damage seems legit, although all the other modifiers are 25%, so that would fit, too.

Comment: @lois6b In the other "real" pokemon game (ie on 3DS, GB), all critical hit was 150% of the base damage. (Some move can have higher bonus because of their effect)

Comment: This is currently false, crits have been tested not to be implemented even though they are in the GAME MASTER file: https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4wzll7/testing_gym_combat_misconceptions/